# Sublime Text Prompt to Save File

Tags: sublimetext2

I often will have a scratch pad in ST that I then close via Ctrl-F4.  It always prompts me to save it, which I find to be a pain.

Is there a setting in ST where I can either change to default of this dialog to "Close without saving", or do not even prompt me at all if it is a new file (i.e. has no name).

[image]

Comment: This link might help: [Don't prompt empty, untitled tabs](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1037). However, this requires you to clear all text before you close via Ctrl+F4 - only one less keyboard press than the dialog.

Comment: @colti that forum discussion is from 2010, and covers Sublime version 1, which is completely obsolete. That plugin won't work in ST2 or greater, as the API has changed.

Comment: My bad - I merely intended it as a reference, not to use the code directly. The idea is fairly similar to your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set a tab to be a scratch buffer (doesn't prompt to save when closed). With the desired tab opened, open the console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> and type:

```
view.set_scratch(True)
```

then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and close the console with <kbd>Esc</kbd>. You can now close the tab whenever you want without being prompted. Of course, you can manually save the contents if you wish.

If you would like to have **all** new buffers set to scratch by default, you'll need a plugin. Create a new Python file in Sublime with the following contents:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class SetNewScratchBuffer(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_new(self, view):
        view.set_scratch(True)

    def on_save(self, view):
        view.set_scratch(False)
```

Save the file as `Packages/User/set_new_scratch_buffer.py` where `Packages` is the folder opened when selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** (`~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages` on Linux with ST2). Once saved, it should automatically become active, although you can restart Sublime to make sure. Now, all new buffers created with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> or **`File -> New File`** will automatically have the scratch attribute set. This will be disabled when the file is saved, so you don't accidentally destroy changes to an opened file.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I did not need to restart ST.  I am on ST3 beta, BTW.  A real gem.  Thanks.

Comment: Still works. Using ST3 on OSX Sierra, Ubuntu and Win10. Thanks –